# Background images in SSRS report resizing on export to PowerPoint

Tags: ssrs, reporting

We are experiencing an issue with SSRS 2016, when we export a report with a background image to PowerPoint.  The image displays properly in the designer (VS 2015), and in preview as well; it also displays properly if exported to PDF or Word.  When exported to PowerPoint, the image is reduced to roughly 1/3 of the intended size.  We have attempted changing the DpiX and DpiY device information settings, to no avail.  We then tried enlarging the background image to 3x the screen size; this worked for the PowerPoint export, but now the image extends well beyond the view in the designer, preview, and other export formats.

We formerly used Aspose for this one critical report; however, the verion we currently have of Aspose does not work with SSRS 2016.

Comment: Check this link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4115/exporting-sql-server-reporting-services-reports-to-powerpoint/

Answer (score 2):

While this is not an answer but a work around that works for me.

You need to have both a small image , and a larger version of the image imported into your report.  Then use the following code to display the large image when exporting to PowerPoint.

The following code should be used in the rectangle's `BackgroundImage.Value` property

```
=iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PPTX","LargeImage","SmallPage")
```